# Animate CSS properties by numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, numbers

I want to create an animation in which the color changes when the mouse approaches a certain element. I found this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/t5Kts/) where the mouse distance is displayed. Is there an efficient way to implement the color change via the number output? I'm not very experienced in JavaScript, so I was looking for something that could help and found this code-snippet:

```html
<p>Fun level <span id="fun-level" style="color: red;">0 %</span>.</p>
```

```js
var percent_number_step = $.animateNumber.numberStepFactories.append(' %')

$('#fun-level').animateNumber({
    number: 100,
    color: 'green',
    'font-size': '30px',
    easing: 'easeInQuad',
    numberStep: percent_number_step
  },
  15000
);
```

But I'm not sure how to apply that to my situation.
I also found this [jQuery plugin](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/approach/) which does exactly what I want, but the color change doesn't work, so I want to redo this script myself.

Comment: Inside the mousemove call on the snippet, I added `$element.css('background-color', 'hsl('+distance+',100%,50%)');`. This changes color hue depending on distance. Quick and hacky just to give an idea

Comment: Yes, this kinda works. But in [my case](https://codepen.io/EYT/pen/WyeaLY) the element already has a color and the the new color should be added to the old one. But to be more specific I made a div with a linear gradient as background-color which should change to a color or even better to a different gradient. Im pretty sure its a pain to animate it to a different gradient.

Answer (score 1):

do you want this?

This code gets darker as you approach the circle.

```js
var ball = document.getElementById('ball')
document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler)
function mouseMoveHandler (e) {
     var x = e.clientX
     var y = e.clientY

     var diffX = Math.abs(x - ball.offsetLeft)
     var diffY = Math.abs(y - ball.offsetTop)
     ball.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${diffX}, ${diffY}, ${diffX + diffY})`
}
```

```css
#ball {
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     background-color: gray;

     border-radius: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     top: 50%;
     margin-top: -25px;
     margin-left: -25px;
}
```

```html
<span id="ball"></span>
```

Comment: This is pretty cool, but [in my case](https://codepen.io/EYT/pen/WyeaLY) I want change the element that already has a specific color to another specific color, or to be more precise I made a div with a linear gradient as background-color which should change to a color or even better to a different gradient. I am not really sure how I could achieve this with your code. Do you have any idea how I could do this?